# Notation in harmonic analysis

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

in the Paper "[The multilinear restriction estimate: a shoort proof and a refinement](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.03336.pdf)" the author Ioan Bejenaru uses the brakets $\langle,\rangle$, for example in the inequality 2.5.

What does this notation mean?

Comment: It stands for [inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html).

Comment: Many times, angle brackets means average.

Answer (score 3):

In this case these are *Japanese brackets*, defined most commonly as
$$\langle x\rangle = (1+|x|^2)^{1/2}.$$

This should be understood as a smoother variant of $1+|x|$.

Comment: What's the point of writing $|x|^2$ if it's always the same as $x^2$?

Comment: $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, @AkivaWeinberger